# How to rotate matrix of button

Tags: java, android

In my layout I have matrix of buttons with images so I want rotate buttons column wise alternatively right to left and left to right so I can see blank buttons without images.

Answer (score 0):

jus check it out

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#postRotate%28float%29

may b work for you